# Avraham's Strange Happiness to Death?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

Since והיה generally refers to something *not* bad,

> [Vayikra Rabba](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.11.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (11:7) -  כל מקום שנאמר ויהי אין שמחה והיה אין צרה

why does Avraham use the word to start the following potentially tragic statement ([Bereishis 12:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#12))?

> וְהָיָ֗ה כִּֽי־יִרְא֤וּ אֹתָךְ֙ הַמִּצְרִ֔ים וְאָֽמְר֖וּ אִשְׁתּ֣וֹ זֹ֑את וְהָֽרְג֥וּ אֹתִ֖י וְאֹתָ֥ךְ יְחַיּֽוּ׃
>
> If the Egyptians see you, and think, ‘She is his wife,’ they will kill
> me and let you live.

Comment: I think that qualification of Chazal (attributed to the [Anshe Knesset HaGedolah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Assembly), [Meg. 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.10b.4?with=all&lang=bi)) is limited to when the narrator is describing an event as opposed to when ‘ויהי’ or ‘והיה’ is when an individual (e.g. Avraham) is speaking.

Comment: My general answer to all inconsistencies of this kind is R' Yochanan's statement in Kiddushin 34a - "אין למדין מן הכללות" (כללים) - meaning that ALL the generalization of the interpreters (like Midrashim) are partial, and can not be learned extensively on all cases.